# Code works in Chrome and Firefox, but doesn't work in IE11

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer-11

I have this small program that basically compares to sets of numbers and then will let me know if there are any matches and what those matches are. It works just fine in Chrome and Firefox, but when I try it in IE11, and hit the button, nothing appears and it doesn't seem to work. I have looked at other forums and topics but nothing I have tried seems to work. Any ideas?

Heres the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"
<HTML><HEAD><META content="IE=5.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">

<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=unicode">
<SCRIPT>
function check() {
var a = document.getElementById("a").value.split("\n").filter(function(num) { return num.length > 0 });
var b = document.getElementById("b").value.split("\n").filter(function(num) { return num.length > 0 });
var results = "";
var numMatchesFound = 0;
for (x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < b.length; y++) {
        if (a[x] == b[y]) {
            numMatchesFound++;
            results += "<br>" + b[y];
        }
    }
}
results = "<br>Found " + numMatchesFound + " matches." + results;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = results;
}
</SCRIPT>

<META name="GENERATOR" content="MSHTML 10.00.9200.16798"></HEAD> 
<BODY>
<H1>Match finder</H1>
<P> Entries can be words, 
numbers, or whatever.</P>
 <H2>Paste a list of entries, one per line, in this 
box:</H2><TEXTAREA id="a" rows="10" cols="30"></TEXTAREA> <BR>
<H2>Paste another list of entries, one per line, in this box:</H2><TEXTAREA id="b" rows="10" cols="30"></TEXTAREA> 
<BR><BUTTON onclick="check()" type="button">Check for matches</BUTTON> <BR>
<DIV id="result"></DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: What does it say in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "Developer Tools", in the "Console" tab:

Object doesn't support property or method 'filter'
File: test.html, Line: 7, Column: 1

Despite the function reportedly being supported as of IE9 (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp), and Microsoft describing how to use it (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679973(v=vs.94).aspx), this is not available for some reason.

Thank goodness for jQuery = )

Or try modifying your meta tags. Pretty sure you told IE to pretend like it was IE5. I stripped your meta tags out and it worked just fine.